# Getting a string instead of variable content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dumb question here.

When I click in one check-box, I need to get the ID of the "n_loadX1" (or others similars) and load the content of this guy into another element.

```
    var n_loadX1  = $("#loadX1").html();
    var n_loadX2  = $("#loadX2").html();
    var n_loadX3  = $("#loadX3").html();
```

In other lines I have:

```
    var loadThis = this.$.find('.jdash-body').attr('id');

    this.$.find(".jdash-body").html(loadThis);
```

"This" reefers to a parent element.

When I try to load directly "n_loadX1", it works and I get my HTML code perfectly, but when i try to get the "loadThis" var I just get a string with the ID of the element.

What I am missing?

Comment: $(this).find('.jdash-body')  ... Ok can you post your code (When I try to load directly "n_loadX1", it works and I get my HTML code perfectly,)

Comment: Sure. 

It is just this line: this.$.find(".jdash-body").html(n_loadX1)

I tried what you said, but it did not work.

Comment: your question is not clear enough to understand what you trying to do .. try to make [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
var loadThis = $(this).find('.jdash-body').attr('id');

    $(this).find(".jdash-body").html(loadThis);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it, but i just get the a string with ID of the elements.

Comment: can you post ful function?